# Subscripts in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an iPhone app and I have cells of a UITableView.  I want some of the cells to have subscripts of "f" and "0".  Is there anyway to do this, maybe using unicode or something?

Answer (score 0):

UILabels, which is what the standard UITableViewCells use to display the data cannot contain subscripts.

It sounds like what you need to do is to create your *own* class, based on UITableViewCell, I'm which you can lay the text out in a way that better suits you, and use *those* cells in your UITableView.

It is easy to create a class based on UITableCellView directly in XCode, including a XIB, which can be visually edited right in Interface Builder.